# Symfony3- can´t access to collections data (get)

Tags: symfony, collections, get

I have an object with several collection. I saved the data correctly and then, when I do "object->getCollection()", I didn´t obtain the data.

**This are my entities:**

***Persona:***

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="PersonaDomicilio",mappedBy="idPersona",cascade={"persist"},orphanRemoval=true)
 */
public $domicilios;

public function __construct() {
    $this->domicilios = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function getDomicilios() {
    return $this->domicilios;
}

public function addDomicilio(PersonaDomicilio $persona_domicilio) {
    $persona_domicilio->setIdPersona($this);
    $this->domicilios[] = $persona_domicilio;
    return $this;
}

public function removeDomicilio(PersonaDomicilio $persona_domicilio) {
    $this->domicilios->removeElement($persona_domicilio);
}
```

***PersonaDomicilio:***

```
/**
 * @var \AppBundle\Entity\Persona
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Persona",inversedBy="domicilios")
 * @ORM\JoinColumns({
 *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_persona", referencedColumnName="id_persona")
 * })
 */
protected $idPersona;
```

The collections are null when I dump persona, and when I dump persona->getDomicilios() too.